# VB.NET: Decompressing/Reforming a sentence from text file EDIT: w/ code

Tags: vb.net, compression

So I have a VB.NET console program where the user is able to enter a sentence, the sentence is then split by each word and given a value. The program then checks for any duplicate words and adds the position the duplicate words appear in with the first.

For example (As I understand that may not have been well explained):
- User inputs "hello my name is hello"
- Program splits sentence and assigns values as such: "hello 1, my 2, name 3, is   4, hello 5" (Each word and number pair are in arrays) 
- Program detects duplicate words and adds numbers to the first as such: "hello 1 5, my 2, name 3, is 4"
- Words and numbers are written to text file

Now the words need to read from the text file. I am using the LineInput(1)/File Open functions to read from the text file and splitting each line of the text file by a space, so that the numbers and words are separate. However, when printing the words back out into the console as a sentence, the words that have duplicates only appear once, since they only appear once in the text file but with two numbers.

I understand the problem but was having trouble finding a way of fixing it, although it may just be that I need to write to the text file in a different way/format. Would be really grateful for anyone who could help/give me tips.

```
Module Module1
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim textInput As String
Dim finalTextInput(1) As String

Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your sentence(s)")
    Dim sentence As String = Console.ReadLine()

    Dim sentenceSplit() As String = sentence.Split(" ")

    For Each element In sentenceSplit
        sentenceSplit(i) = element & " " & i
        i += 1
    Next

    Dim output As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    For Each current In sentenceSplit
        ' split current input
        Dim currentSplited = current.Split(" ")
        Dim word = currentSplited(0)
        Dim trailingNumbers = currentSplited(1)

        ' if it already exists
        If output.ContainsKey(word) Then
            ' add trailing numbers
            output(word) = output(word) & " " & trailingNumbers
        Else
            ' new input
            output.Add(word, trailingNumbers)
        End If
    Next

    ' create new array from dictionary
    Dim newArray = output.Select(Function(x) x.Key & " " & x.Value).ToArray()

    FileOpen(1, "compressed.txt", OpenMode.Output)

    For Each element In newArray
        PrintLine(1, element)
    Next
    FileClose(1)


    Read()
End Sub
Sub Read()
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to decompress your sentences? Y/N")
    Dim input As String = Console.ReadLine()

    If input.ToLower() = "y" Then

        FileOpen(1, "compressed.txt", OpenMode.Input)

        Do Until EOF(1)
            textInput = LineInput(1)

            finalTextInput = textInput.Split(" ")

            Console.Write(finalTextInput(0) & " ")
        Loop

        FileClose(1)
    ElseIf input.Tolower() = "n" Then
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using our system")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        End
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose one of the options")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500)
        Console.Clear()
        Read()
    End If
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: If you want help debugging your code, you should probably include your code in the question.

Comment: @Mark Alright thanks I usually do but I thought this explanation was enough as I know what the problem is, just needed a fix

Answer (score 0):

I propose you the following code. For compressing the string, we split an input text by space, then - looping for each word - we proceed in checking where into the array an equal string appears. In the case, we substitute every equal word with the index of the original one.

If a word has been already processed, it will be represented by a number: so, if we find a number, we jump to the next word.

In completing the loop, we save the file.

The decompress method does the reverse.

```
    '-- Compress and save
    Dim ftext As String = "hello my name is hello and my greeting is hello is end"
    Dim flist() As String = ftext.Split(" ")

    For i As Integer = 0 To flist.Count - 1

        If IsNumeric(flist(i)) Then Continue For

        For k As Integer = i + 1 To flist.Count - 1
            If flist(k) = flist(i) Then flist(k) = i.ToString()
        Next

    Next

    IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\temp\hello.txt", String.Join(" ", flist.ToArray()))

    '-- Read and decompress
    Dim text As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("c:\temp\hello.txt")
    Dim tlist As List(Of String) = text.Split(" ").ToList

    For i As Integer = 0 To tlist.Count - 1
        If IsNumeric(tlist(i)) Then
            tlist(i) = tlist(Val(tlist(i)))
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox(String.Join(" ", tlist.ToArray()))
```

After the compress routine, my string "*hello my name is hello and my greeting is hello is end*" becomes

[image]

and after the decompress, it looks again like the original

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for that although I'm not sure it is quite what I need. I've edited the post to include my code so you can see what I have got already.

Comment: Hi. The only thing that differs seems to me to be the used classes (i've used arrays, while you used Dictionary), and the method of entering the input text (which i've enclosed in a variable for brevity reasons). Can i ask what you mean when you say that's not what you need? It seems to me the result is correct. Thank you

Comment: Since my compressed words and numbers do not write to the text file in the same way as yours does, I'm not sure it would work